# How to give dynamic columns in select query by selecting columns from another table result

Tags: oracle

I am looking for some help on below issue:

I am getting column names from the XML column in one query, and I wanted to pass those column names in another query.

below is the sample structure of my query:

```
with temp1 as (
select x 
from table1)

select (select distinct x from temp1)  from table2
```

when I have given like above it is displaying column name text, not data from another table, can someone please help me to solve the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Sample data, please?

Comment: Are you asking how to select some_column from table, but this string ('some_column') is the output of previous query? In this case you need [dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS631).

Comment: How many dynamic columns do you want at a time?  If you can live with just one, there are some neat tricks using `DBMS_XMLGEN`.  If you need multiple dynamic columns, then maybe something like [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4/) could help.  But before you look into either approach - are you *sure* you need code this dynamic?  It's usually best to use the application to generate the SQL, instead of using dynamic SQL in SQL.